# Does C++11 guarantee the local variable in a return statement will be moved rather than copied?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, rvo

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(const vector<int>&) {}
    A(vector<int>&&) {}
};

A f()
{
    vector<int> coll;
    return A{ coll }; // Which constructor of A will be called as per C++11?
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

**Is `coll` an `xvalue` in `return A{ coll };`?**

**Does C++11 guarantee `A(vector<int>&&)` will be called when `f` returns?**

Comment: In your example,   `A{coll}` will be constructed in the caller context and will use the constructor `A(const vector&)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++11 does not allow `coll` to be moved from. It only permits implicit moves in `return` statements when you do `return <identifier>`, where `<identifier>` is the name of a local variable. Any expression more complicated than that will not implicitly move.

And expressions more complex than that will *not* undergo any form of elision.

Comment: +1; Note that there where quirks, where if the type of `<identifier>` didn't match the return'd type, it wasn't moved.  This was fixed in either a defect report or a change in C++14, I forget which; but, if you are using a legacy compiler (or risk using one), a `move` when the types do not match exactly may be wise (and has no cost).  Meanwhile, when the types match exactly, the `move` would block elision.  This is only of concern if you are using relatively ancient compilers.

Comment: @vsoftco: Oh, the *expression* is a prvalue, and it will behave as such. But `coll` will not be moved into `A`, and that's what the question was asking.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks! Yes, realized after I wrote the comment. At first I thought that `A` has a move ctor and that the question was about the `A` object itself.